# CSS mousewheel scroll not working on safari

Tags: css, scroll, safari, scrollwheel

I tested my website in different browsers and found out that my scrollwheel is not working in safari, however scrolling with the scrollbar works (or tapping the mousewheel)

I tested other websites and it's not a problem in other website, also it works fine in chrome, ie, vivaldi, opera

URL: http://www.comicconbrussels.com/en/homepage-english-4/

Comment: Downvoted: please provide any reproducible code right there, so as we don't have to inspect the sites.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your page in chrome in device mode. So, before refreshing the page i can't scroll with touch. Works only twitter frame, so i think that you have some problems with embedding your twitter frame. Try to remove twitter block.

Also you can try to remove your "Nice scroll"

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("html").niceScroll({
        cursorborder:"", 
        cursorcolor:"#525252", 
        boxzoom:true, 
        cursoropacitymin: 0.5,
        cursoropacitymax: 1,
        cursorwidth: 5,
        mousescrollstep: 50
    });
});
```